# Loading animation freezing in Loki

Tags: release-loki, wifi, appcenter

As I have stated in the title the loading icon animations are seem to be freezing. I have experienced this in the AppCenter update tab and during the Wi-Fi connection. However after a while the processes are completed. Is this issue related with the Loki update ? Do you know any bug report for this issue ?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem when I install new updates/apps. It takes usually a few startups and then it's back to normal.- I believe that it perfoms some installation processes before loading desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen a bug like this (then again, I rarely look at the bug reports :P ).  Could this be a graphical glitch?  The system may be doing a large update, and it requires a great deal of system resources.  This could be what's causing the freeze: the system can't properly draw the animations due to the use of the resources.

Comment: Well I guess 16gb of ram with i7 processor and gt860m can handle this these kind of processes am I wrong?

Comment: Well then, I may be mistaken. :-/

Comment: You might be rigt but if thats the case I dont think that is caused by tye hardware maybe some kind of optimization problem ?

Comment: If it's an optimization problem then it's one hell of an optimization problem.